# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy - Remove Hyphen only using String.Format

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C Custom policy I want to remove hyphen '-' from objectId(GUID) claimtype and assign it to another claimtype.

Eg:

Input : e8023a66-30ed-4e31-a17e-c013081704a0 
Ouptut : e8023a6630ed4e31a17ec013081704a0

I have currently tried the following:

```
<InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="00000000000000000000000000000000,{0}" />
<InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0:################################}" />
<InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0:#}" />
```

I am using FormatStringClaim transformationmethod in ClaimsTransformation to achieve the same however the value is getting assigned to the target claimtype with hyphen.

Can you please help me in removing hyphen?

Note: 
I cannot use any other String operations like Replace or Split as Azure AD supports only String.Format method.

Comment: I’m curious, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using FormatStringClaim transformationmethod in ClaimsTransformation to achieve the same however the value is getting assigned to the target claimtype with hyphen.

It sounds like you incorrectly configured your Claims Transformation and have assigned your original GUID as both your input and output claims. You need to update the ClaimTypeReferenceId with the claim you want to store your modified GUID in.

Example:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="RemoveHash" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="originalGuid" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="modifiedGuid" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```